# Como acrescentar ou eliminar pontos de dispersão em um gráfico mecanicamente?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Olá, bom dia!

Gostaria de saber uma rotina para acrescentar ou eliminar pontos de dispersão em um gráfico de forma "mecânica" com o click do mouse sobre o gráfico!

Pretendo trabalhar com alguns mapas, de marcar alguns pontos específicos, mas de forma visual sobre o gráfico. Há um bom tempo a trás eu vi em algum lugar um script que permitia fazer isso com relação a eliminar os pontos discrepantes em um gráfico de distribuição normal QQ, bastando apenas clicar sobre os pontos no gráfico e estes eram removidos... porém não lembro mais onde vi.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o pacote gatepoints lhe seja útil.

```
library(gatepoints)
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = c(rnorm(n = 100, mean = 4, sd = 2), 
                       rnorm(n = 10, mean = 10, sd = 10),
                       rnorm(n = 5, mean = 4, sd = 20)),
                 y = c(rnorm(n = 100, mean = 6, sd = 3), 
                       rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = 1),
                       rnorm(n = 5, mean = 6, sd = 25)))
{
  grDevices::X11()
  plot(df, col = "red", pch = 16)
  pontos_selecionados <- gatepoints::fhs(df)
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Selecione os pontos de interesse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Clicar em "parar" na *window*.

---

```
id <- data.frame(id = as.numeric(as.character(pontos_selecionados)),
                 remove = 1)

df2 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(id = 1:nrow(df)) %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(id, by = "id") %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(remove == 0)

ggplot2::ggplot(df2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
df3 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(id = 1:nrow(df)) %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(id, by = "id") %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(remove = as.factor(remove))


ggplot2::ggplot(df3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y,
                 shape = remove, fill = remove), 
             show.legend = F, size = 3, alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,22)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como eu faria para usar o comando "pontos_selecionados <- gatepoints::fhs(df)", em um arquivo raster usando o ggplot2?
ex:
{grDevices::X11();
df <- expand.grid(x = 0:5, y = 0:5);
df$z <- runif(nrow(df));
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_raster();
pontos_selecionados <- gatepoints::fhs(df)
 }